# Logout when using ibm appid adapter with SAML

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

We are using the IBM appid adapter ( https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-istio-adapter ) on openshift service mesh for authentication against a SAML IDP . How can I logout from the SAML session?

Comment: Have you tried this one already? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-cd-sso#cd-sso-log-out

Comment: I believe http://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-cd-sso#cd-sso-log-out  is for cloud directory , aint using cloud directory, am using an enterprise SAML IDP.